# Is there a difference between creating tf.Variable and keras.layers.Layer.add_weight()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've seen both approaches in Tensorflow documentation:

---

#1

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                         self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
```

---

#2

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

---

Is there a fundamental difference between creating a variable with self.add_weight() or tf.Variable() inside your custom layers? Examples are taken from
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference between creating a tf.Variable and using keras.layers.Layer.add_weights().

A `tf.Variable` is a general-purpose variable that can be used to store any data type.

While a `keras.layers.Layer.add_weights()` method is used to add weights to a layer. The weights are stored in a dictionary, where the keys are the names of the weights and the values are the tensors that represent the weights.

For example, you could create a `tf.Variable` and use it to store the number of times a user has visited a website. You could then use that variable to calculate the probability that the user will visit the website again.

However, you could not use `keras.layers.Layer.add_weight()` to store the number of times a user has visited a website. This is because `keras.layers.Layer.add_weight()` can only be used to create weights for layers.

In general, you should use `tf.Variable` if you need to create a variable that can be used in any context. You should use `keras.layers.Layer.add_weight()` if you need to create a weight for a layer.